Global.asax CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found
I got an ASP.NET MVC 5 project for support. When I opened solution in VS (2022), it converted projects from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.8.
I tried to build it, but I got several errors:

...\Global.asax(10,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XXXX' could not be found

Where XXXX - namespace's from other project's in this solution.
Lines the errors point to:
<%@ Import Namespace="XXXX" %>

Output path of all projects points to the same folder. Target framework everywhere is set to 4.8.
Why it can't one project see its neighboring projects?
